# How to apply a function over two multidimensional arrays without using a loop?

Tags: r

I have two multidimensional arrays and i want to iterate though a specific dimension and apply a function. If my inputs were 1-d arrays I could use mapply, but here I need to specify the margin or dimension of both inputs.

See the simple example below:

inputs

```
array_a <- array(runif(60), dim = c(5,4,3))
array_b <- array(runif(60), dim = c(5,4,3))
```

say I want to apply a function over the 3rd dimension that takes two 2d array as inputs:

```
my_fun <- function(input_1, input_2){
  return(colSums(input_1 * input_2))
}
```

I can do this with a loop easily:

```
output <- array(NA, dim = c(3, 4))
for( i in 1:3){
  output[i,] <- my_fun(array_a[,,i], array_b[,,i])
}
```

but is there a way to vectorise this and not use a loop?

Comment: Is `my_fun` the exact function of interest or is that a stand-in for the real function?

Answer (score 7):

**1)** if `my_fun` is the function of interest as opposed to representing some other function for purpose of illustration then it is already vectorized.

```
output2 <- t(my_fun(array_a, array_b))

# check
identical(output, output2)
## [1] TRUE
```

**2)** If it is just a stand-in for some other function then

```
output3 <- t(sapply(1:3, function(i) my_fun(array_a[,,i], array_b[,,i])))

# check
identical(output, output3)
## [1] TRUE
```

**3)** or using a list comprehension

```
library(listcompr)

output4 <- gen.matrix(my_fun(array_a[,,i], array_b[,,i]), i = 1:3)

# check
identical(output4, output)
## [1] TRUE
```

**4)** or using a list comprehension with parallel processing -- only use this if the inputs are large.

```
library(eList)
library(parallel)

cl = auto_cluster(2)
clusterExport(cl, c("my_fun", "array_a", "array_b"))

output5 <- t(Mat(for(i in 1:3) colSums(array_a[,,i] * array_b[,,i]),
  clust = cl))

close_cluster(cl)

identical(output5, output)
## [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 6):

If that's the exact calculation you are doing, you can use

```
t(apply(array_a * array_b, 3, colSums))
```

Since you are doing multiplication that's already vectorized, then you can use `apply()` to apply a function over the third dimension of the arrays. We use `t()` to transpose to match your desired `output` but that's mostly cosmetic.

A more general solution would be

```
t(mapply(
  function(a, b) {colSums(a*b)}, 
  apply(array_a, 3, identity, simplify=FALSE), 
  apply(array_b, 3, identity, simplify=FALSE))
)
```

We use `apply()` to extract a list of values separated by the third dimension of the arrays. Then we use `mapply` to map over those lists and apply the function. Again we use `t()` to transpose the results to match what you got in your `output` matrix.

Comment: Upvoted. An "intermediate", and perhaps more readable, generic solution would be something like `t(apply(array_a * array_b, 3, \(x) apply(x, 2, sum)))`, where the last `sum` can be replaced by whatever you want to apply over the 2nd dimension, when iterating over the 3rd dimension.